# C# - Merge list items into one item based on some matching values

Tags: c#, list, linq, merge

I have a list of items (`List<Tasks> tasks`), like this one:

```
Id                     Action               Source       Target
-------               ---------            --------     ---------
1                      Save                 12           18
4                      Save                 18           21
7                      Save                 21           23
6                      Save                 23           25
10                     Save                 25           27
16                     Save                 29           31
0                      Edit                 31           37
```

What I want to do, is to merge the rows that have the same (`Source` and `Target`) and the same `Action`. For example, what I need at the end should look like this:

```
Id                     Action               Source       Target
-------               ---------            --------     ---------
22                     Save                 12           27
16                     Save                 29           31
0                      Edit                 31           37
```

Which means, all the items that have the same `Action`(in my case here Save) should be merged to one row/item **but only** in case the `Target` value of the upper item is equal to the `Source` value of the follower item. A follower is the lower item.

For example, upper is item `Id = 1` and lower/follower is item `Id = 4`. So the record that follows.

Is there any way to do this with linq avoiding the too many foreach loops?
Maybe something like Hierarchies with CTE in SQL. But I'm still not finding the correct syntax, so that's why I didn't paste any code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since it's a list you can use index and single pass `for` loop to combine current item with previous/next. What are many foreach loops you are talking about? Not sure how you get `Id=22`  though.

Comment: Have a look at GroupBy().

Comment: @Sinatr Id = 22 is an internal id property of the object and not the index in the list.

Comment: Can you assume that only the next task is a candidate for the merging?

Comment: @Robert, yes GroupBy is a good candidate but I need some help in the logic

Comment: How do you get 22 from 5 items with Id=1,4,7,6,10 ? It's not a sum.

Comment: @Sinatr, i guess my problem is not to interpret from where 22 came, the problem is something else. I told you, 22 is just an example from me, you can ignore it and take into consideration only the Action, Source and Target columns.

Comment: use distinct if u just need to get only singular values.

Comment: What makes me think that `GroupBy` doesn't help is this: _"but only in case the target value of the upper item is equal to the source value of the follower item"_ What is a _follower_?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, with follower i mean the lower item. For example, upper is item Id = 1 and lower/follower is item Id = 4. The record that follows :)

Comment: think in the way Merge sort works. You will be able to make this more simpler , faster and maintenable

Comment: You should try to find a solution with pure SQL in a stored procedure. Will be hard to fnd a set based approach without loops. If all records are already in memory and you can do it with pure Linq-To-Objects there might be an elegant approach

Comment: @TimSchmelter, yes the records are in memory. Linq-To-Objects can help

Comment: And how in last row of what you expect Edit action got 27 and 30 as source\target?

Comment: @Evk, this was a typo, i corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want "LINQ" solution, you can use `Aggregate` like this:

```
var result = tasks.Aggregate(new List<Item>(), (acc, current) =>
{
    if (acc.Count > 0)
    {
        var prev = acc[acc.Count - 1];
        if (prev.Action == current.Action && prev.Target == current.Source)
        {
            // update previous target
            prev.Target = current.Target;
        }
        // otherwise just add
        else acc.Add(current);
    }
    else acc.Add(current);
    return acc;
});
```

It starts with empty `List` as accumulator, and feeds items one by one. Then we just add items to accumulator if they do not match criteria, and if they do match - we update previous item instead.

Comment: Your solution assumes tasks is already ordered like this `tasks.OrderBy(x => x.Action).ThenBy(x => x.Source)`

Comment: Yes, but as I understood, OP has predefined order (by id?), so I'm not sure if that should be resorted by `Action` or `Source`. Valid comment still - If I'm wrong, OP can always add required `OrderBy`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it is ordered!! I'm testing if this would be the solution that i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`MoreLinq`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/). There is a function named `Segment` which splits the sequence into subsequences based on some condition:

```
var grouped = tasks
    .GroupBy(t => t.Action, (k, g) => g
        .Segment((s, f, a) => s.Source != f.Target)
        .Select(c => new
        {
            c.First().Source,
            c.Last().Target,
            Action = k
        })));
```

So the sequence is divided and a new subsequence is created on each adjacent pair when `s.Source != f.Target` (`f` is first element and `s` is second in a pair).

Comment: Didn't know about MoreLinq. I'm spinning up a new project to give it a try. Upvote from me.

Answer (score 1):

Something like a CTE query. First select seed nodes (no records pointing to the SOURCE) then in the do-wile loop change Targets to get the end target of each chain. No previous order is required.

```
public class Tasks
        {
            public int Id;
            public string Action;
            public int Source;
            public int Target;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Tasks> tasks = new List<Tasks>{
                                    new Tasks{Id=1,Action="Save",Source= 12,Target=18},
                                    new Tasks{Id=4,Action="Save",Source= 18,Target=21},
                                    new Tasks{Id=7,Action="Save",Source= 21,Target=23},
                                    new Tasks{Id=6,Action="Save",Source= 23,Target=25},
                                    new Tasks{Id=10,Action="Save",Source= 25,Target=27},
                                    new Tasks{Id=16,Action="Save",Source= 29,Target=31},
                                    new Tasks{Id=0,Action="Edit",Source= 31,Target=37},
            };

            var collectTasks = (from t in tasks
                                where !tasks.Any(t1 => (t1.Target == t.Source)&&(t1.Action == t.Action)&&(t1.Id!=t.Id))
                                select t).ToList();

            foreach (var ct in collectTasks)
            {
                do{
                    var t1 = from t in tasks where ((ct.Target == t.Source)&&(ct.Action == t.Action)&&(ct.Id!=t.Id)) select t;
                    if (t1.Count() == 0) { break; }

                    ct.Target = t1.First().Target;
                 } while (true);
            }

        foreach (var t in collectTasks)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Action = {0}, Source = {1}, Target = {2}", t.Action, t.Source, t.Target);
        }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need just one loop using index to access list items, starting from `1` and combining current item with previous if their `Action` match and `Target` of previous item is equal to `Source` of current:

```
for (int i = 1; i < items.Count; i++)
    if (items[i].Action == items[i - 1].Action && items[i].Source == items[i - 1].Target)
    {
        items[i - 1].Target = items[i].Target;
        items.RemoveAt(i);
        i--; // to have same index after i++
    }
```

That would not change `Id`, so it will be `1` and not `22` as you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication33
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>() {
                new Task() { Id = 1, Action = "Save", Source = 12, Target = 18},
                new Task() { Id = 4, Action = "Save", Source = 18, Target = 21},
                new Task() { Id = 7, Action = "Save", Source = 21, Target = 23},
                new Task() { Id = 6, Action = "Save", Source = 23, Target = 25},
                new Task() { Id = 10, Action = "Save", Source = 25, Target = 27},
                new Task() { Id = 16, Action = "Save", Source = 29, Target = 31},
                new Task() { Id = 0, Action = "Edit", Source = 31, Target = 37}
            };

            for(int i = tasks.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                int source = tasks[i].Source;
                List<int> match = tasks.Select((x, index) => new { x = x, i = index }).Where(x => (x.x.Target == source) && (tasks[i].Action == tasks[x.i].Action)).Select(x => x.i).ToList();
                if (match.Count > 0)
                {
                    tasks[match[0]].Target = tasks[i].Target;
                    tasks.RemoveAt(i);

                }
            }

        }
    }
    public class Task
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }
        public int Source { get; set; }
        public int Target { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This procedure will do what you need in one-pass, preserving the "Id" values of items that can't be merged.

You'll see it works on an ordered list so strictly speaking there is some LINQ-hidden activity there; but generally speaking you'll find that LINQ queries incur an overhead which make then always slower than for-loops over arrays.

```
    private List<Task> Merge(List<Task> list)
    {
        var result = new List<Task>();
        var maxId = list.Max(x => x.Id) + 1;

        // order list for this algo to work
        var listO = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Action).ThenBy(x => x.Source).ToArray();

        // create seed and counter
        Task seed = listO[0];
        var ctr = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < listO.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (listO[i + 1].Source == listO[i].Target && listO[i + 1].Action == listO[i].Action && listO[i + 1].Action == seed.Action)
            {
                // if the next is the last, merge it now
                if (i + 1 == listO.Length - 1)
                    result.Add(new Task() { Id = maxId++, Action = seed.Action, Source = seed.Source, Target = listO[i].Target });

                // the next item qualifies for merge, move to next
                ctr++;
                continue;
            }

            // next item does not qualify for merge, merge what we have or just add the item if ctr == 0
            result.Add(ctr == 0 ? seed : new Task() { Id = maxId++, Action = seed.Action, Source = seed.Source, Target = listO[i].Target });

            // reset seed record + counter
            seed = listO[i+1];
            ctr = 0;

            // if the next item is the last, it belongs in the list as is
            if (i + 1 == listO.Length - 1) result.Add(seed);                
        }

        return result;
    }
```